# What is a title of a short story that the aliens store the Encyclopedia Britannica with a mark in a matchstick?

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, aliens, hard-sci-fi

I think that the author is [Jorge Luis Borges](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jorge_Luis_Borges), but I was looking for his short stories on the internet and I didn't find a short story from him about the aliens and matchstick.

More or less the short story is about the first contact of aliens with humanity and they ask for the whole of human knowledge. The people give them the Encyclopedia Britannica. The aliens say that the books are too big, and with a precision machine put a mark in a matchstick. The mark is a number representing the "compressed" texts of all books.

Comment: Oooh, I know this story. Brb, hunting for it ...

Comment: Richard Feynman discussed putting the entire Encyclopedia Britannica on the head of a pin [in his talk "There's Plenty of Room at the Bottom"](http://www.zyvex.com/nanotech/feynman.html), but that's not quite the idea you (and I) are thinking of.

Comment: Everyone should read that speech.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This was featured in Martin Gardner's book *[Aha! Insight](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/397238.Aha_Insight)* (1978).

It is The Amazing Code on page 48 of the [omnibus edition](https://books.google.com/books?id=3HzwNVMQOZkC&pg=PA48).  In the follow-up discussion on the next page, Gardner does not cite any scientific or literary sources, so I think he made up the encoding method himself.

Comment: Thanks, it is the story...well my remembers are about the same story in spanish but yes, it is. And the remembers are about aliens (but my mind sometimes mix freak things).